# calling an argument as a string not working - C

Tags: c, input, verify

I'm trying to write a function that will take an input and return it when it is valid

The function is constantly printing the error message even if the input is correct.

How can I pass the argument through to verify without it being evaluated as boolean beforehand?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char verify(char argument[256]){            //function to check an input is valid
    char input;
    while(1){
        input = getchar();
        while(getchar()!='\n');             //clear buffer
        if(argument){
            break;
        }
        printf("That is not a valid input. Try again: ");       //error message
    }
    return input;
}

int main(void){

    char input;

    printf("Enter an alphabetical input: ");
    input = verify(input>64&&input<91||input>96&&input<123);   //checks to see if the ASCII value of the input corresponds to a alphabetical char

    printf("Input is: %c",input);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think this

 `input = verify(input>64&&input<91||input>96&&input<123);   //checks to see if the ASCII value of the input corresponds to a alphabetical char` means

Comment: The verify function asks the user to input a char until it satisfies the argument. 
This value then gets assigned to the char "input".
Is that wrong?

Comment: For a start does input have a value?

Comment: Then you are passing to verify a boolean at best - not an array

Comment: It is initialized without one and the user is expected to input a char to it within verify. Which is meant to check if the input character is alphabetical then return that value to the char "input" in main

Comment: Can you suggest a better way of doing this?

Comment: You are passing into verify `input>64&&input<91||input>96&&input<123`

Comment: But `input`  is not defined

Comment: And that lot is a boolean not a array of characters

Comment: Agh I understand you now, a 1/0/error is all that will be passed to the verify function. Is there a better way I can pass this through?

Comment: Usually that sort of logic is in the `verify` function itself. You can use function pointers if you want to get all fancy.

Comment: Could you give an example of this please? I can see the probelm but don't know a way around it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `if (argument)` you need to actually put your boolean conditional there: `if (input>64&&...&&input<123)` When you do that, the `verify` function no longer needs to take an argument.

C doesn't support what you're doing trying to pass the conditional as an argument. It just so happens that the type of that expression is compatible with the `char[]` type `verify` takes; which is why your code is compiling at all. C does in no way knows you are wanting to pass a conditional expression for `verify` to evaluate. It just doesn't work like that.